# How to make JScrollPane dynamic adjusting

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I am trying to make a dynamic tabs with the option to add new ones in the application and some buttons next to it... To do so I have a main class:

```
private static void initAndDisplayUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(...)

        tabbedPane = new TabbedPane();

        insertTab(tabbedPane, TabFactory.createTab(), true);
        insertNewTabButton(tabbedPane);
        ...
        }
 }
```

Container class:

```
public class TabbedPane extends JPanel {public TabbedPane() {
        this.captions = new TabCaptions();
        this.tabs = new ArrayList<Tab>();
        this.contentContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(captions, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(contentContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

...
}
```

And a `TabCaptions`:

```
public class TabCaptions extends JPanel {
    private TabCaption selectedTab;
    private JComponent tabsPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel buttonsPane;

    public TabCaptions() {
        createUI();
    }

    private void createUI() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        add(createTabsPane());
        add(createButtonsPane());
        add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    }

    private JComponent createTabsPane() {
        tabsPane  = new JPanel();
        tabsPane.setOpaque(false);
        tabsPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tabsPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabsPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        return tabsPane;
    }
    ...
}
```

As a result I have a region with the tabs and some button next to it. However the app window draws a scrollPane with some weird size... I would like to display this "add new tab" button right next to the tabs that are created, resize it when the new tab is being added BUT with the functionality to display a scrollbar once it hits the maximum window width. I already have the scrolling but how can I make the behaviour of this dynamic position of new page?

Answer (score 0):

> I already have the scrolling

Not based on the code you have provided:

```
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabsPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    return tabsPane;
```

You need to add the JScrollPane to the frame, so you need to return the scroll pane from the method:

```
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabsPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    //return tabsPane;
    return scrollPane;
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was experimenting with the code and pasted a wrong version. Anyway, when I return `scrollPane` I do have a scrolling and the buttons for moving around the view work but the size of panel seems quite weird - around the 3/4 of the space - and changes when I add tab. I'd like this pane to take the whole possible area and change only on window resize.

Comment: `I'd like this pane to take the whole possible area` - the layout of the top level panel should be a BorderLayout, then child components added to the `CENTER` get all the space available. If you are using nested panels then you need to make sure each nested panel takes all the space available.